# How to display object properties as separate fields in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am writing API documentation using OpenAPI 3.0. At the moment I have:

```yaml
paths:
  /script/update:
    post:
      tags: 
      - "Script"
      summary: Update a script
      operationId: updateScript
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        "404":
          description: Not Found
      requestBody:
        description: A script object in order to make the request
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                subsite_id:
                  type: string
                script:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    script:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/ScriptType'
                    type:
                      type: string
                      enum:
                        - custom
                        - interface
                        - freshbot
                        - feeder
                        - getter
                        - smcf
                    status:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/ScriptStatus'
                    comment:
                      type: string
                      format: string
                    reason:
                      type: string
                      format: string
```

To problem comes when I try to use to Swagger UI.
The only thing that appears is the following:
[image]
What I want is that the `script` object can be filled out field by field for each of the properties it has, like the `subsite_id`. What am I missing?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not really suited for sending nested objects. Did you mean `application/json` maybe? Or `multipart/form-data` (a multipart body with text and JSON parts)? If the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type is correct, how do you expect the nested object to be serialized? (Can you give an example of the raw request body?)

Comment: @Helen Thank you very much. I forgot about that. Yeas I need to send nested objects and it has to be json. I changed it and it works. But it still gives to edit the json in raw format. Is it possible to change that when using `application/json` or `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI 3.x and 4.x do not have a form editor for JSON objects, so all JSON data needs to be entered in the JSON format: `{ "prop": value, ... }`

Here's the corresponding feature request you can track:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771