# Swagger, how to put object properties in separate fields in the interface?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it possible in Swagger in the interface to put the properties of an object in separate fields, as shown in the screenshot below? Swagger version 2.0 or 3.0.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PadN9.png)

Importantly: These individual object fields must be in the request Body.

What i have done now:

1) The code:

```
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                example_obj:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    field1:
                      type: string
                    from:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        field2:
                          type: string
                    field3:
                      type: string
```

2) my result:

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkgI6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger not displaying object properties in UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52385204/113116).

Comment: As explained in the ^^ linked Q&A, Swagger UI v3 does not have a JSON form editor. There's an open feature request here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771

Comment: @Helen But can i implement this at the 2.0 version?